# How to get timestamp through eosjs in seconds?

Tags: eosjs, eosio.cdt

I want to get the timestamp of the block in Seconds but eosjs library returns it in an iso string format. Is there a way to receive timestamp in seconds or convert the string to seconds?

Example:
What I get:

> block_time: '2021-03-12T05:45:56.000'

What I want:

> block_time in seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass block_time string to instantiate Date object. It contains milliseconds, so you need to divide it by 1000 to get seconds.

code:

```js
const block_time = '2021-03-12T05:45:56.000';
const seconds = Math.floor(new Date(block_time) / 1000);
console.log(seconds);
```

output:

```
1615527956
```